# autogenerate uuid in micronaut entity

Tags: groovy, micronaut

I have this entity (I am using micronaut with mongoDB):

```
class Fruit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    String id

    @GeneratedValue(GeneratedValue.Type.UUID)
    UUID uuid

    @NonNull
    @NotBlank
    String name

    @Nullable
    String description
}
```

when I do inserts using this entity, the @ID field is generated and inserted properly but the UUID is ignored. How can I autogenerate UUIDS in Micronaut entities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@GeneratedValue` is for IDs only as defined in JPA spec:

> Provides for the specification of generation strategies for the values
> of primary keys.
>
> The GeneratedValue annotation may be applied to a primary key property
> or field of an entity or mapped superclass in conjunction with the Id
> annotation. The use of the GeneratedValue annotation is only required
> to be supported for simple primary keys. Use of the GeneratedValue
> annotation is not supported for derived primary keys.

You can use `@AutoPopulated` for this case.